# Cannot assign - must be instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following form in my django app. I overrode the constructor so I could limit the choices that appear in the field 'classes' so that only classes that students are signed up to will appear.

```
#forms.py
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        classes = [Classes.objects.filter(students__username=self.user.username)]
        class_list = list()
        for c in classes:
            for single_class in c:
                cl = Classes.objects.get(id=single_class.id)
                class_list.append([cl, single_class])
        self.fields['classes'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=class_list)

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('classes', 'name')
```

However, doing this gives me a Cannot assign "Class1234: Test class" - "Test.classes" must be a "Classes" instance. When I print class_list, I get this:

```
[[<Classes: Class1234: Test class>, <Classes: Class1234: Test class>],[<Classes: Testing: 2nd class>, <Classes: Testing: 2nd class>],[<Classes: 3rd: Class>, <Classes: 3rd: Class>]]
```

To me, that DOES look like the actual class objects, so I don't understand why this doesn't work. For reference, here are my models and the view:

```
#models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


class Classes(models.Model):
    classcode = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    classname = models.TextField()
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.classcode, self.classname)


class Test(models.Model):
    classes = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    points = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.name)

#views.py
def add_test(request):
    added = False
    form = TestForm(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            added = True
    return render(request, 'site/addtest.html', {'form': form, 'added': added})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[<Classes: Class1234: Test class>, <Classes: Class1234: Test class>],[<Classes: Testing: 2nd class>, <Classes: Testing: 2nd class>],[<Classes: 3rd: Class>, <Classes: 3rd: Class>]]
```

This is a list of lists, that's probably why it fails. But your problem has a much more elegant solution anyway.

No need to do that in `__init__`. Simply override `classes` field in your form and define the queryset. Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

And if this is a restriction that should be applied on a database level as well, consider using `limit_choices_to`. Read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Comment: Thanks for your help - exactly what I was looking for